# Foreign method access in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I m beginner.
I'm trying to access a related item of the model `Product` in the template layer of a `ProductDetailView`. How can I retrieve the `ImageField`s of the `Product`s' `Brand`'s `BrandImages`? I have to traverse one forward and one reverse `ForeignKey`.

Edited to include **get_logo_url**

What is wrong with the get_logo_url function?

**products/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    brand = TreeForeignKey('Brand', verbose_name='parent category', related_name='products', default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', verbose_name='parent category', related_name='products', default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
            unique_together = ('slug', 'category')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productimage_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        return img
```

**brands/models.py**

```
def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.brand.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    new_filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.id, file_extension)
    return "products/%s/%s" % (slug, new_filename)

class BrandImage(models.Model):

    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='brandimages') 
    is_slider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_logo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.brand.title

   def get_logo_url(self):
      if is_logo:
         img = self.brandimage_set.first()
         if img:
            return img.image.url
         return img

    def thumb(self):
        if self.image:
            return u'<img src="%s" width=120 height=120 />' % (self.image.url)
        else:
            return u'No image file found'
    thumb.allow_tags = True

class Brand(MPTTModel):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='parent brand', related_name='brands')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('brands', kwargs={'path': self.get_path()})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**template**

```
<div class="rightpart">
    <div class="prodbrand h2">
        <h1>{{ product.brand }}</h1>        
        <div class="brandlogo">
            {% for image in product.brand.brandimages.all %}
                <img src="{{image.get_logo_url }}"/>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prodtitle"><h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
 class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/product.html'

    def get_context_data(self , *args , **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView , self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        instance = self.get_object()
        context["related"] = Product.objects.get_related(instance)
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='products'),
```

*is there a way to access foreign fields in django templates like this?*

Comment: I guess foreign fields can be simply used in template just like other fields. If not you can pass the brand image object in context along with other fields.

Comment: from where would you like to access it, i.e.: what object do you have loaded in the template?

Comment: thats what i want to know...how to load object here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a `ListView` to display your products there's several things to notice:

- `get_context_data()` must return a dictionary: `return context` is missing
- `super().get_context_data` should be called with `*args,**kwargs` incase you decide to subclass the  `ProductListView` at a later point in time.
- `super().get_context_data` will contain a `object_list` key which contains the list of objects returned by `get_queryset()`, in your case objects of class `Product`.

When accessing a property from a template, django will attempt to call it without parameters if it is callable. This is often useful e.g.: for `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}` or `product.brand.brandimages.all`

Your template should look like this:

**product_list.html**

```
{% for product in object_list %}
    <div class="rightpart">
        <div class="prodbrand h2">
            <h1>{{ product.brand }}</h1>      
            <div class="brandlogo">    
                {% for image in product.brand.brandimages.all %}
                    <img src="{{image.image.url}}"/>
                {% endfor %}
            </div><!-- End brandlogos -->
        </div><!-- End prodbrand -->
        <div class="prodtitle">
            <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End rightpart -->
{% endfor %}
```

Take into account that this will incur several database lookups from the template. You generally want to avoid the case that your presentation layer reaches into the database, which is why you should prefer to do the database lookup in the corresponding `View`. Also for property access consider using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) as appropriate to avoid unneeded database queries.

**views.py**

```
class ProductListView(ListView):

    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all().active()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["now"] = timezone.now()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We call super() for potential subclasses
        queryset = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset.prefetch_related('brand__brandimages')
        return queryset
```

Comment: wont **product.brand.brandimages.all** work ?? as i need to show the brand of that particular product..

Comment: Edited to include the template...i have a set of images in brand ...how can i use the first image in the set?

Comment: cant i use ''def thumb''' function to show the brand thumb on the product template ?

Comment: it is working .....but 'product.brand.brandimages.all' will give more than one images...

Comment: i want to use just one image of many brand images in the set....can we define a function in a view and populate through context....what is the best way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92479/discussion-between-aditya-singh-and-sebastian-wozny).